# How to list all lines in a field with Progress 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

An address field in a Progress database evidently is multiple lines.  So if I do something simple like:

```
for each customer where customer-number = "123" no-lock.

display customer-number
        customer-name
        customer-address.
```

I get results of:

```
123  John Smith  123 Easy St.
                 c/o Jane Smith
                 Apartment C12
```

I want results of:

```
 123  John Smith  123 Easy St.  c/o Jane Smith  Apartment C12
```

I've tried Entry - but get an error if an element does not exists.  I am trying to export to CSV and want each line to be another column and if a column does not exists then it is blank.

Any help will be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the delimiter is a newline then something like this should work:

```
define variable n as integer no-undo.
define variable i as integer no-undo.

define variable address as character no-undo.

output to value( "customer.csv").
for each customer no-lock:
  address = "".
  n = num-entries( customer-address, "~n" ).
  do i = 1 to n:
    address = address + entry( i, customer-address, "~n" ) + " ".
  end.
  export delimiter "," customer-number customer-name trim( address ).  
end.
output close.
```

or, if you just need to change the delimiter within the customer-address field:

```
output to value( "customer.csv").
for each customer no-lock:
  export delimiter "," customer-number customer-name replace( customer-address, "~n", "," ).  
end.
output close.
```

(And, actually, my original code is really just replacing ~n with a space so you could do that too...)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Now I am only getting the first line in the export.  The result is:  

123  John Smith  123 Easy St.

Comment: I also think I need a comma to delimit each element in the ENTRY.

Comment: There is a slight error...  I forgot to add the delimiter to num-entries().  I'll fix that above.

Comment: If you want to replace the newlines with commas then a simpler approach would be to use the REPLACE() function rather than looping through the entries.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!  Thank you so much!